# Four different CSS elements below each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following layout:

1. navigation header: fixed height and fixed position from top,
2. wide horizontal image banner: fixed position, but resizable with main window,
3. content area: text starting under image banner, with auto scrollbar, and
4. information footer: fixed height and fixed position from bottom.

My problem is #3, the actual content text area. I can't use a fixed position due to the resizable image, but I can't use a relative position with regard to #3 either by placing the content DIV with overflow:auto within the image DIV -- because then the image starts scrolling as well. I think I have to make the content text a child of the image banner because of the variable image size, but I'm unable to get it exactly the way I want.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
... navigation banner ...
</div>


<div id="topimg">
<img src="images/01-shop.jpg" width="100%">

<div id="content">
... text ...
</div>

</div>


<div id="footer">
... footer content ...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav {
position: fixed;
height: 47px;
width: 90%;
margin-left:5%; 
margin-right:5%;
}

#topimg {
position: fixed;
width: 80%;
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
top: 90px;
}

#content {
position: ???
width: 80%;
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
position: fixed;
height: 27px;
width: 90%;
bottom:10px;
margin-left:5%; 
margin-right:5%;
}
```

Does anyone have a good suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you demonstrate your problem using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) it would help everyone get a better grasp of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z90gtamy/)

I'm not sure you really need to do a lot of `position: fixed` for a straight-forward layout.

(I added the borders just to make things easier to see)

CSS

```
#nav {
  height: 47px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left:5%; 
  margin-right:5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#topimg {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-right:10%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-right:10%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:10px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left:5%; 
  margin-right:5%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkkhbku8/5/**

This should be achievable if I understand your question properly. There's a bit going on here so I will do my best to explain.

First, you'll want to add a psuedo element below the header to fill the gap between the header and the image banner. This is for when the text scrolls up. It should be the same background colour as the document body.

Next, since the image banner div is fixed in position but you want it responsive to the browser width you will need to give it a height of 0px and use padding to make it's height a % of it's width. This padding will be based on the ratio of your image but may require some tweaking since the holder is set 10% off each side. For an image which is 16:9 you would normally use `padding-bottom: 56.25%` but based on the 10% left and right margin the ideal padding-bottom here is 45%. You can tweak this for your image.

```
#topimg {
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 45%;
}
```

If you don't know the ratio of the image then you'll need to use some JS to find it out and set the padding.

For the content, you will want to firstly push it down with `margin-top: 90px` (the height of the header) and then padd it down with `padding-top: 45%` (the height of #topimg). This will ensure it tucks up under the image div as it resizes. You will also want to put a margin bottom on it so it pushes away from the footer when scrolled.

Lastly, so you can't see the text below the fixed footer you will want to keep it at the bottom and use `padding-bottom: 10px` instead of `bottom: 10px` and then give it a solid background colour. You could of course use another psuedo element here but was just as easy to use padding.

Hope that helps.